# Vuex Modules Are not Registered As Expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm recently facing some troubles while using Vuex.
I have two modules: user and categories.

I use the following code to register the two modules in the store/index.js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import categories from "./categories"
import user from './user'
console.log(categories)

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user: user,
    categories: categories,
  }
})
```

After execution, I am able to find states in both modules in the path `$store.state.moduleName.moduleStates`. However, I am unable to find mutations nor actions.

I first tried to set namespace to false, the mutations and actions were not registered as global mutations and actions. (There are no such mutations or actions at all)

I then tried to set namespace to true, the mutations and actions were not registered as namespaced mutations and actions neither. (`this.$store.commit('moduleName/mutationName')` doesn't work; an error message pops up: `[vuex] unknown action type: categories/getAllCategories`)

I tried to debug by printing out the 'categories' module object and the store object and I found that:

1. Modules themselves are correctly defined. Mutations and Actions are correctly defined in the module object.
2. Module states are correctly registered in store.state (as per previously tested)
3. Module mutations and actions are not correctly registered in `store._mutations` and `store._actions` (no matter the modules are namespaced or not, the mutations and actions don't appear as global or namespaced properties); `store._mutations` and `store._actions` show as empty objects.
4. Modules can be seen in `store._modules.root._children` and `store._modules.root._rawModule`

The result of console.log(categories) and console.log(this.$store) are shown:
[image: console.log(categories)]

---

[image: console.log(this.$store)]

Can someone help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well... After several hours, I solved this issue by myself.

The bug is that I wrongly created a store object in modules and exported it.

In module files, we should export as follows:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

not:

```
export default new Vuex.store( {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
})
```